# valueState vanishes on focus out from sap.m.StepInput

Tags: sapui5

I have a validation where, `StepInput` throws value state error when user reduces the step to zero. The `valueState` red color border appears on change but vanishes on focus out from the input field.

```xml
<StepInput value="{/step}" valueState="{= ${/step} === 0 ? 'Error' : 'None'}" />
```

Comment: Since the bug is now fixed, please accept the answer that was helpful to resolve the issue. This would also help future readers to find the answer more quickly. Please read _[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)_

Answer (score 0):

The `StepInput` control has a private method called `StepInput.prototype._verifyValue` that is triggered on focus out (`StepInput.prototype.onfocusout`). This method checks whether the entered value is between the min and max. If the entered value is valid, then it sets the value state to `None`. One way to get around this is to add your own method on focus out using `addEventDelegate`. You might need to do this anyway if you want the value in the `StepInput` to be multiples of 10 as the input will accept any number in the interval [min,max].

Answer (score 0):

The [issue](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2347) is now fixed with UI5 1.68. You can see that the `valueState` now stays even after focus out: https://jsbin.com/hiwihaw/edit?js,output

Also you need to replace the `'None'` operand with `undefined` in order to let the control apply the default behavior (setting 'Error' state if the `value` exceeds the `min`/`max`):

```xml
<StepInput value="{/step}" valueState="{= ${/step} === 0 ? 'Error' : 'None' undefined}" />
```